# AllowAnonymous doesn't work as expected in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, plesk

In an **ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Server-Side Blazor app**, I am not able to get the AllowAnonymous working for a **post type of request web API**. The **get** requests do not have any issues.

Along with the solution for it work, please advise me about the needed security. Perhaps I lowered the security in my trials to get the post request work.

These 3 logs appear for every post request:

[image]

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
                  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EpisodeContext>();

        services.AddMvc(options=> { 
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(option => { option.DetailedErrors = true; });
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddAuthorization(config =>
        {
            config.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

            config.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                 policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
        });
    ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
          
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

API Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]

public class DailyContentController : ControllerBase
{
     [HttpPost("likeepisode"), AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<bool> LikeEpisode(string episodenumber)
    {
        bool result = await _CDService.LikeEpisode(episodenumber);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Plesk Hosting Settings:

[image]

Web Application Firewall

[image]

Comment: The 300 error suggests this has nothing to do with security.

Comment: If this is a blazor hosted app in the same solution, you could place a break point on the method to see if it's getting it.

Comment: @Qudus On the local machine it works, only when it is hosted on Plesk it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to stop the unintended redirect by setting the preferred domain to none in the hosting settings:

[image]